# value not getting updated in ElementTree in lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using lxml in python.

```
from lxml import etree
d = etree.parse("input.xml")
t1 = etree.Element('year')
t2 = etree.Element('gdppc')
t1.text = '2016'
t2.text = '123456'
```

When I print t1 and t2,

```
print etree.tostring(t1)
print etree.tostring(t2)
```

Correct output is printed. But it's not getting updated in 'd'.

```
print etree.tostring(d)
```

**input.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
   <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>        
</data>
```

How to update it in 'd'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d` is not related to `t1` or `t2` in any way. By doing `etree.Element('year')` or `etree.Element('gdppc')` you are *initializing new independent elements*. Instead, if you want to update existing `year` or `gdppc` elements inside `d`, find them first:

```
d = etree.parse("input.xml")

t1 = d.find('.//year')
t2 = d.find('.//gdppc')

t1.text = '2016'
t2.text = '123456'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Alecxe :)